# Adjusting the size of Excel range pasted to Outlook mail using Word .PasteandFormat

Tags: excel, vba, image, outlook, ms-word

I created code to copy a cell range into an email.

A) This gets me an image where the text is blurry and overly bold

```
.PasteandFormat wdChartPicture
```

B) This gets me the correct text clarity but I need to zoom the email itself to x300 to visualize the numbers and letters clearly

```
 .PasteandFormat wdMatchDestinationFormatting
```

How can I paste in a size that is clear to visualize?
Alternatively how can I increase the pasted image so that the recipient doesn't have to zoom x300 to see the email?

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub Send_Email()

Dim OutApp As Object
Dim OutMail As Object
Dim table As Range
Dim pic As Picture
Dim wb  As Workbook, ws As Worksheet, wsSettings As Worksheet
Dim wordDoc
Dim strHTMLBody As String
Dim lonZoom As Long

Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)
Set wb = ThisWorkbook
Set wsSettings = wb.Worksheets("Settings")

'grab table, convert to image, and cut'
Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Summary")
Set table = ws.Range("B8:AA338")
ws.Activate
table.Copy
Set pic = ws.Pictures.Paste
pic.Cut

'create email message'
On Error Resume Next
With OutMail
    strHTMLBody = strHTMLBody & "</span>"
    
    .HTMLBody = strHTMLBody
    .To = wsSettings.Range("Email_To").Value
    .Subject = wsSettings.Range("Email_Subject").Value
    .Display
        
    Set wordDoc = OutMail.GetInspector.WordEditor
    With wordDoc.Range
        .PasteandFormat wdMatchDestinationFormatting
    End With
End With
On Error GoTo 0

Set OutApp = Nothing
Set OutMail = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: FYI I have tried other .PasteandFormat wd combinations but nothing seems to get the results I'm after

Comment: Ranges have a `CopyPicture`  method: `table.CopyPicture xlScreen, xlPicture`.  You can try access the emails images and resizing then.

Answer (score 0):

You deal with a message body which is an HTML markup. So, you can save the generated image in Excel as a file and then attach it to the mail item and use in the body markup in the way you like.

The [Attachments.Add](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.attachments.add) method allows to attach a file. But you need to use an embedded image (not visible attachments). You need to set up the CID property on the attachment and use the CID attribute in the HTML markup.

Refer to the image in the HTML body through the `cid` attribute

```
<img src="cid:xyz">
```

Then add the attachment using `Attachments.Add`.

After that you can set the `PR_ATTACH_CONTENT_ID` property (DASL name `http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x3712001F`) using `Attachment.PropertyAccessor.SetProperty`. This will be your `cid` value.